# Interpolate in SQL based on subgroup in django models

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following `sheetinfo` model with the following data:

```
|    Trav    |   Group    |   Subgroup   | Sheet_num  | T_val  |
|  SAT123A01 |   SAT123   |      A       |     1      |   400  |
|  SAT123A02 |   SAT123   |      A       |     2      |   0    |
|  SAT123A03 |   SAT123   |      A       |     3      |   0    |
|  SAT123A04 |   SAT123   |      A       |     4      |   0    |
|  SAT123A05 |   SAT123   |      A       |     5      |   500  |
|  SAT123B05 |   SAT123   |      B       |     5      |   400  |
|  SAT123B04 |   SAT123   |      B       |     4      |   0    |
|  SAT123B03 |   SAT123   |      B       |     3      |   0    |
|  SAT123B02 |   SAT123   |      B       |     2      |   500  |
|  SAT124A01 |   SAT124   |      A       |     1      |   400  |
|  SAT124A02 |   SAT124   |      A       |     2      |    0   |
|  SAT124A03 |   SAT124   |      A       |     3      |    0   |
|  SAT124A04 |   SAT124   |      A       |     4      |   475  |
```

I would like to interpolate and update the table with the correct T_val.

Formula is:

```
new_t_val = delta / (cnt -1) * sheet_num + min_tvc_of_subgroup
```

For instance the top 5:

```
|    Trav    |   Group    |   Subgroup   | Sheet_num  | T_val  |
|  SAT123A01 |   SAT123   |      A       |     1      |   400  |
|  SAT123A02 |   SAT123   |      A       |     2      |   425  |
|  SAT123A03 |   SAT123   |      A       |     3      |   450  |
|  SAT123A04 |   SAT123   |      A       |     4      |   475  |
|  SAT123A05 |   SAT123   |      A       |     5      |   500  |
```

I have a django query that works to update the data, however it is SLOW and stops after a while (due to type errors etc.)

My question is there a way to accomplish this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do this as one database call doesn't exist in stock Django. 3rd party packages exist though: https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update

Example of how that package works:

```
rows = Model.objects.all()
for row in rows:
    # Modify rows as appropriate
    row.T_val = delta / (cnt -1) * row.sheet_num + min_tvc_of_subgroup
Model.objects.bulk_update(rows)
```

For datasets up to the 1,000,000 range, this should have reasonable performance. Most of the bottleneck in iterating through and .save()-ing each object is the overhead on a database call. The python part is reasonably fast. The above example has only two database calls so it will be perhaps an order of magnitude or two faster.

Comment: Thank you for the link - I'm struggling with how I'd implement this to interpolate as as the calculation is based off of group and subgroup.

Comment: Edited with an example

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the example. I am struggling a bit on how to now determine `delta`, `cnt` and `min_tvc_of subgroup` but I can definitely say you've helped me a lot!